# Get TextView text size after autosizing

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I use Autosizing TextViews(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) and want to get text size in runtime(programmatically). But text size is always static(what I set in xml). Is it possible to get the correct text size, after autosizing?

Comment: ok, I can get it like myTextView.post{
here
}
but how to het BEFORE user will see the layout.

Comment: I have the some problem. Have checked in few points in fragment life cycle and even in onResume there is still given the static size. In onPause is already OK, but of course it doesn't solve the problem.